# Making a Game Movie/Story Scene

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am close to finishing my first cocos2d game. Now I want to make a small movie/story to show when the user launches the game app. The game should first show the 15 seconds story (animated story) like in MonsterShooter, JailBreaker, AngryBirds, or the like. When you tap on the  story, it takes you to the main menu.

My question is: **What to use to make the story?** Other than making an actual scene with lots of animations is there any other tool that I can use to create an animated story and embed it to cocos2d layer?

Comment: You could use screen recoding software to get some video footage. Without wanting to endorse any particular product, Camtasia Studio has worked well for me, for making demos.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to make a video, you could try with adobe premiere, final cut, Windows Movie Maker, iMovie, adobe after effects (just to name a few), then to play the video use the CCVideoPlayer from [cocos2d-iphone-extensions](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions)

Comment: But I don't want to show video controls on the screen (play, rewind, etc).